# How to spoof 'to' and 'from' fields from actual email recipient and sender addresses

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib, spoofing

For my use case, I would like to manually set the displayed email addresses in the `"to"` and `"from"` field headers of the email, separate from the actual email recipient and sender. I am currently using the smtplib library in python and have managed to accomplish the desired effect with the `"to"` field and was looking to replicate it for the `"from"` field as well.

What I have so far:

```
EMAIL_ADDRESS_G = 'ayush.warikoo77@gmail.com'
from email.message import EmailMessage
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS_G, EMAIL_PASSWORD_G)
    
    # What I would like to be displayed in the email
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = "Test"
    msg["To"] = 'test@gmail.com' # shows up
    msg['From'] = 'test@gmail.com' # does not show up
    msg.set_content("Test body")
    
    # Where I would like to be setting the actual email sender and recipient
    smtp.send_message(msg, from_addr=EMAIL_ADDRESS_G, to_addrs=EMAIL_ADDRESS_G)
```

The above code produces the following:

[image]

As shown, the `"to"` field displays the desired set address, while the `"from"` field displays my actual email instead of `"test@gmail.com"`. I believe it is being set when I call login with the account, but I am unsure if I can override it. Also happy to use another python email library, if it is not possible with `smtplib`.

Current --> Desired

```
To: test@gmail.com
From: ayush.warikoo77@gmail.com --> test@gmail.com
Actual Sender: ayush.warikoo77@gmail.com
Actual Reciever: ayush.warikoo77@gmail.com
```

Note that this would be used for archiving purposes, where a designated email client might actually be sending the emails, however, I would like the email to use the to and from fields of the message it is trying to document. So the desired displayed "from" field is separate from the actual sender.

Comment: The actual sender is you right? and in the comment of your code you say `I would like to be setting the actual email sender`  so it looks to me like it indeed shows the actual sender of the email. Why do you want to fake the sender of the email?

Comment: I'm using this for archiving purposes, where a worker email client might actually be sending the emails, however, I would like the email to use the to and from fields of the message it is trying to document. So the desired displayed "from" field is separate from the actual sender.

Comment: but then why do you say "I would like to be setting the actual email sender" in the comment of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticated Gmail SMTP prevents you from spoofing the From header, presumably to prevent abuse.

For archiving purposes, using IMAP’s `APPEND` command will allow you to place whatever you like in your own mailbox (as it doesn’t count as sending email) and may be a better solution.  (You will need to use an App Specific Password or OAUTH to login though).

Comment: Using IMAP Append also generally bypasses spam and reputation scanning on the SMTP server. It however does have rate limits.

Comment: I see, what would be the best course of action if I would be sending the emails to a third-party inbox for archiving, that I do not have direct access to and therefore don't have control over the receiving end?

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to set up my own SMTP server